# Why are mini-batches degrading my conv net MNIST classifier?

Tags: neural-network, gradient-descent, mini-batch-gradient-descent, convolutional-neural-network

I have made a convolutional neural network from scratch in python to classify the MNIST handwritten digits (centralized). It is composed of a single convolutional network with 8 3x3 kernels, a 2x2 maxpool layer and a 10 node dense layer with softmax as the activation function. I am using cross entropy loss and SGD.

When I train the network on the whole training set for a single epoch with a batch size of 1, I get 95% accuracy. However, when I try with a larger batch size (16, 32, 128), the learning becomes very noisy and the end accuracy is anywhere between 47%-86%. Why is it that my network performs so much worse and noisier on mini-batches?

Comment: Assuming that the gradients are averaged when using mini-batches, have you made sure that the number of weight updates is the same?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "the number of weight updates is the same", but yes, i am averaging gradients, including weight gradients during updating. But i no longer have this problem with the network since i've changed some things. I dont know what the problem was though.

Answer (score 0):

Your model is very small for a convnet. 1 conv layer, 1 maxpool and 1 fc is very shallow. Try adding more layers and batchnorm2d after each conv layer followed by relu. No pool layers.

Comment: This would likely result in better performance, but do you have any idea why it is when I use mini-batches that the performance worsens? Is it bad to use mini batches on a shallow network?